# Java thread still reads from Database even the query finished

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, websphere

i have this issue where in even if the query process in Oracle ended, thread in Java Spring is still waiting or reading from DB Connection. this query loads for more than 30 minutes in the Oracle DB, after it ends, i saw web container thread in java and it's still waiting on the DB side.

all i see in thread dump is - locked <33019fca> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection), but i cant see any thread related to 33019fca, plus the web container is in RUNNABLE State so it puzzles me.

my question is, what are things do I need to check? I know the query is the root cause as it should not load that long, but why does web container is still waiting when the query ended in the DB side?

Application:

- Java 6
- OJDBC 6
- Oracle DB
- Spring
- Websphere 8

Java Thread:

```
"WebContainer : 11" - Thread t@191
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:128)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:429)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:397)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:220)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:48)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:938)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4901)
        **- locked <33019fca> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)**
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:5631)
        **- locked <33019fca> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)**
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:956)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.execute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:623)
        at com.xx.xx.xxxx.dao.xxDataQueryJdbcDAO.getData(xxDataQueryJdbcDAO.java:346)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

from fiddler perspective, it is still waiting for the response.

[image: stuck fiddler session]

from Oracle Side,
I cant see the query loading anymore plus all connections related to schema is inactive.

Comment: Query that runs over 30 min??? You really need to redesign your app and db schema, this will never work efficiently.

Comment: @Gas, yes, the db procedure is handled by other team, i reported it but just want to do checking on our end also. this looks good after an exadata patch over the weekend.